# How do I have text display within the inside of a stacked bar graph in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

How do I have insert text within the stacked sections of a highcharts stacked bar graph ( https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked ).

My graph will really only have two columns, and they'll have the y-axis reversed and displayed as so: https://jsfiddle.net/ogjz9ra0/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Bananas']
    },
    colors: ['#1b98ee', '#1366a6'],
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [4726.78]
    }, {
        name: 'Brian',
        data: [4250.00],
    }]
});
```

What I'd like is to be able to inject text into each of the columns.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CDttfeB9mqI5r9voYalsLtEeH0OSs3Ey/view?usp=sharing

I'm still relatively new to HighCharts, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you all so much again!

I did some googling, and most of the results talk about having the text render inside the bar for non-stacked bar charts. Note that the placing for the problem I'm trying to solve is in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datalabels`  [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.dataLabels) like this :

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        // console.log(this) // uncomment this line to see all params available
        return 'custom text here'
      }
    }
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/y1bdjnhu/1/)

Comment: oh nice! do you have any suggestions on how to make it "responsive" ? If there is too much of an imbalance in the chart -- to hide one and not the other?

Comment: Hi @Brian Zhou, `allowOverlap` option is disabled by default: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.dataLabels.allowOverlap You can create a line break by `<br>` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I super follow @ppotaczek . can you elaborate? Feel free to ignore if it's too much work.

Comment: Brian Zhou - I mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/as94d0up/